# SQLite Android after clicking on insert button it crashes(insert button meant for creating and inserting table and table value)

Tags: android, android-sqlite

code:

```
public class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public String str=null;
public static final String TABLE_SPEECH = "takespeech";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
public static final String SPEECH_TEXT = "speech";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "speechtext.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private SQLiteDatabase database;
private DatabaseOpenHelper dbHelper;
private static final String TABLE_CREATE =
                "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SPEECH + "(" + COLUMN_ID +" INTEGER, " +
                 SPEECH_TEXT + " TEXT);";

    DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
        Log.v("MainActivity", "after creation");
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SPEECH);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException {
        database=dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        database.close();
    }

    public void insert(String getpass) {
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_ID, 1);
        cv.put(SPEECH_TEXT,getpass);
      //    open();
        database.insert(TABLE_SPEECH, null, cv);
      //    close();
    }

   public String readme() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT"+SPEECH_TEXT+"FROM"+TABLE_SPEECH,null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            str = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SPEECH_TEXT));
        }

        return str; 
    }
}
```

And in Mainactivty for a button (yes) for adding and creating table and table values :after clickin on this app crashes.

```
yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view) {  
            try {
               createTable();       
            }
            catch (SQLiteException se) {
               Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
            } 
        }
});
```

This is function called when user clicks on yes button and data is inserted and onCreate() should be called but then it crashes as i click on yes dont knw y.

```
public void createTable() {
    DatabaseOpenHelper dbhelper=new DatabaseOpenHelper(getBaseContext());
    dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    dbhelper.insert(pass);
    String a=dbhelper.readme();
    TextView reads=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    reads.setText(a);
}
```

Comment: Please post a stack trace.

Comment: you will need to format select query correctly by placing space between sqlite keywords as :`Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT "+SPEECH_TEXT+" FROM "+TABLE_SPEECH,null);`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK but OP said he got exception when he try to insert right..?

Comment: @Pragnani : OP saying data is created and inserted successfully but crashed when clicking yes button

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK But brother look at his code, in that he inserts data..Not reading

Comment: i ll try tht thnx i m trying this

Comment: actually mcre8in a voice recogntion app tht stores word recorded in database

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Ok its my mistake haven't look at dbhelper.readme().. sorry..

Comment: @Pragnani : it's ok brother i see only problem with select query

Comment: rest all code is right na ? so i changed tht query prob. tht u mentioned correctly. thnx running the app

Comment: ah listen i actually separated the creation and reading in two diff. functions and called them in try statement in yes button..

Answer (score 0):

In your "createTable" method you're not setting the "database" variable that you're using in your insert, so it is null.  Check your stacktrace and see if the error is in the insert() method.

In createTable() change:

```
dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

to

```
dbhelper.open();
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have i think two problems. First problem is **rawQuery()** method. Look

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT"+SPEECH_TEXT+"FROM"+TABLE_SPEECH, null);
```

Here, you are missing spaces between reserved words. Your output is now like this:

```
selecttextfromtable
```

It not sounds good, isn't? Solution is to add spaces between words and it should work.

```
String query = "SELECT " + SPEECH_TEXT + " FROM " + TABLE_SPEECH;
db.rawQuery(query, null);
```

Second is that you probably passing Context assigned to `NULL`:

```
DatabaseOpenHelper dbhelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(getBaseContext());
```

Change **getBaseContext()** into

```
new DatabaseOpenHelper(YourActivity.this);
```

Comment: yaa thts wht m changing nw

Answer (score 0):

put ui updation inside handler or asynctask

mHandler.post(new Runnable()

{
        @Override
        public void run() 
{
        reads.setText(a);

}
    });